# Switch between a SKScene and a View Controller programmatically?

Tags: swift

I have two blocks that, when they touch, will play an animation then send the player back to the menu screen. However, because the player controls the where the blocks are positioned... etc... I can't segue the scenes using a button or a timer. I was wondering a way to make my scene (GameScene) go to my View Controller (LoginViewController) when my two nodes (ball and paddle) touch. This is the programming I already have for the two touching.

```
func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    // 1
    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody



                   // 2
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }
    // 3
    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == BallCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PaddleCategory {
        let ball = childNode(withName: BallCategoryName) as! SKSpriteNode
        ball.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector.zero
        let paddle = childNode(withName: PaddleCategoryName) as! SKSpriteNode
        self.view?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        paddle.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector.zero


    }
     }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What does "go to" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about creating a segue between the two scenes - naming the corresponding identifier (e.g. in the storyboard) "test" - and when the blocks touch each other triggering a segue like this:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("test", sender: self)
```